# String or binary must be truncated

Tags: sql

I have a problem with my C# code. When I execute it, it says:

> String or binary must be truncated.

This is my code:

```
 using (SqlCommand command = Connect.GetConnection().CreateCommand())
 {

      command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
      command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Adherent VALUES(@Id,@Nom,@Prenom,@Adresse,@N_Tel,@Date_Inscription,@Nbre_Emprunt,@Garentie)";
      command.Parameters.Add("@Nom", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar).Value = model.Nom;
      command.Parameters.Add("@Prenom", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar).Value = model.Prenom;
      command.Parameters.Add("@Adresse", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar).Value = model.Adresse;
      command.Parameters.Add("@N_Tel", System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = model.Mobile;
      command.Parameters.Add("@Date_Inscription", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = (object)model.DateInscrit ?? DBNull.Value;
      command.Parameters.Add("@Nbre_Emprunt", System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = model.NumbreEmprunt;
      command.Parameters.Add("@Garentie", System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = model.Garentie;
      command.Parameters.Add("@Id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = model.ID;
      //model.ID = Int32.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();            
  }
```

This is my db:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Adherent] (
[Id]               INT        NOT NULL,
[Nom]              NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
[Prenom]           NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
[Adresse]          NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
[N_Tel]            BIGINT        NOT NULL,
[Date_Inscription] DATETIME   NOT NULL,
[Nbre_Emprunt]     INT        NULL,
[Garentie]         FLOAT (53) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

and these are the values:

```
 AdhNEW.ID = 123;
 AdhNEW.Nom = "FUSCA";
 AdhNEW.Prenom = "FUSCA";
 AdhNEW.Adresse = "12 rue FUSCA";
 AdhNEW.Mobile = 25698741;
 AdhNEW.DateInscrit = DateTime.Now;
 AdhNEW.NumbreEmprunt = 0;
 AdhNEW.Garentie = 0;
```

Comment: my database is: [Id]               INT        NOT NULL,
    [Nom]              NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Prenom]           NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Adresse]          NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [N_Tel]            INT        NOT NULL,
    [Date_Inscription] DATETIME   NOT NULL,
    [Nbre_Emprunt]     INT        NULL,
    [Garentie]         FLOAT (53) NULL,

Comment: AdhNEW.ID = 123;   
AdhNEW.Nom = "FUSCA";   
AdhNEW.Prenom = "FUSCA";   
AdhNEW.Adresse = "12 rue FUSCA";   
AdhNEW.Mobile = 25698741;   
AdhNEW.DateInscrit = DateTime.Now;   
AdhNEW.NumbreEmprunt = 0;   
AdhNEW.Garentie = 0;

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess here, but you defined the `N_Tel` and `Nbre_Emprunt` fields as `BIGINT` and then passed the values to them as `Decimal`.

`[N_Tel]            BIGINT        NOT NULL,
[Nbre_Emprunt]     INT        NULL,`

`command.Parameters.Add("@N_Tel", System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = model.Mobile;
command.Parameters.Add("@Nbre_Emprunt", System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = model.NumbreEmprunt;`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to put data in a sql column but the data you're stuffing is bigger than the column size definition.    (putting a 21 char string in an nvarchar (20),as an example).

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the DB and the corresponding conversion,
when I get my adherent with function "All ()",  it says:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

there is the code of my function :

```
public IEnumerable<IAdherent> All()
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = Connect.GetConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Id, Nom, Prenom, Adresse, N_Tel, Date_Inscription, Nbre_Emprunt, Garentie FROM Adherent ORDER BY Nom ASC;";
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        yield return (new Adherent()
                        {
                            ID = reader.GetInt32(0),
                            Nom = reader.GetString(1),
                            Prenom = reader.GetString(2),
                            Adresse = reader.GetString(3),
                            Mobile = reader.GetInt64(4),
                            DateInscrit = reader.IsDBNull(5) == false ? (DateTime?)reader.GetDateTime(5) : null,
                            NumbreEmprunt = reader.GetInt32(6),
                            Garentie = reader.GetFloat(7)
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```